# Do bistellar flips preserve shellability?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-stuff, manifolds

I notice there is a strong connection between shellability of simplicial complexes and bistellar flips on these complexes; in particular, adding in a new facet of a shelling induces a bistellar flip on the boundary.

Is it always the case that bistellar flips preserve shellability of  a complex?  In other words, if I apply a bistellar flip to a shellable simplicial complex, is the resulting simplicial complex also shellable?  If so, how can this be seen easily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously not, because there exist non-shellable combinatorial spheres, but any combinatorial $n$-sphere is bistellar-equivalent to the boundary of the $(n+1)$-simplex.

The observation you mentioned is also in the very end of [Lickorish's paper](http://www.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/Lickorish.pdf)